# how to overwrite or create a new try/catch/finally block .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, try-catch, overwrite

I want to overwrite the try/catch/finally block or to create a new myTry/myCatch/myFinally block to have internally a specific and "automatic" behaviors.
For example to Log an exception, the developer must call explicitly the Log(ex) method. => `try{...}catch(Ex ex){ **Log(ex)**; doSomething(); throw; }`

but if the developer forgets to call the Log(ex), then nothing happens.

I want to create a structure able to do something inside it, like the template pattern. something like:

```
MyTryWithAutomaticInternalLog {
 doSomething();
}
MyCatch(Exception ex){
 **//Internally this stores in someplace the exception** 
 doSomething2(ex);
 throw;
}
MyFinally {
 //internally this saves how much time took the execution for example.
 doSomething3();
}
```

There are other options like:
1) Create a wrapper method like
`MyTryWithAutomaticInternalLog(()=>{ doSomething(); }, (ex)=>{ doSomethingOnError(); }, ()=>{ doSomethingInfinally(); });`
and inside the MyTryWithAutomaticInternalLog with a template pattern strategy manage the flow, but again, the developer has to remember to use the method MyTryWithAutomaticInternalLog instead of the very standard try/catch/finally.

2) Avoid use try/catch in the code and manage the exception with a dependency injection pattern. But I want to avoid it.

Are there another options? how can I overwrite the try/catch/finally block? if no, I would be grateful if you provide some technical information and links because I have searched without much luck.

Tkx

Comment: You want automatic logging if and only if the caller forgets to do their own?  Just add the logging and a way for the caller to suppress it. A logging system flag, a class property, or an optional param to the function.  Edit: also you should be using a logging system if this is an actual issue. Log4net or others. These problems have been solved a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, [cross cutting concerns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658105.aspx) (validation, logging, authorization, auditing, etc.) should be factored out of the "normal" part of the application rather than trying to "override try catch".

There is a good MSDN article about [Aspect-Oriented Programming : Aspect-Oriented Programming with the RealProxy Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn574804.aspx).

Similarly, you could use [Interception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852703(v=pandp.51).aspx) with the same aim. There is an article about [interception with Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx) on MSDN, but this feature is also available on some other popular DI containers.

Some application frameworks also have built-in extensions for cross cutting concerns. For example, ASP.NET MVC has [filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg416513(VS.98).aspx) that can be registered globally and then turned on or off for specific parts of the application using .NET Attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap a service with interceptor to implement logging of service calls. It will provide a way to get your exception regardless of how the programmer writes the catch code.

example is in my service layer i bind resolution using logginginterceptor.

This url will give you a nudge in a direction filled with uncertainty, but will allow you to abstract how you can handle exceptions.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx

In addition, you can throw the exception from another layer of code by validation an object. If you (Throw New CustomException("Error 121") your try catch code will know what to do. If you use interception you can handle all types of custom exceptions(derived from System.Exception).